# WPF Window not following mouse when expanding

Tags: c#, wpf

On a new blank WPF app, I noticed that the resizing the window with mouse does not work properly.

When I'm shrinking the window, it works fine. But when I'm expanding it, the window does not follow the mouse until I leave the button, and then the window suddenly jumps to the new size.

It seems that if I move the cursor **really slowly** while expanding, the window follows the cursor; but a bit faster than that and it doesn't anymore.

You can see the issue in a video I recorded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WpQi.jpg).

I tried .NET versions 4.7.2, 4.7.1 and 4.6. All are having the same issue.

I've tried to look this up, but found nothing about this issue anywhere. Does anyone know what is causing this, and how can one fix it?

There's a possibility that this issue is somehow isolated to my machine, and therefore caused by something other than the framework itself. So another relevant question might be whether anyone else sees this behavior on a new WPF project or not.

**Update:** This is the behavior seen in a **new blank WPF project**, with no code changes at all. And the expected behavior is obviously for the window to follow the cursor while expanding, just like it already does when shrinking.

**Update 2:** As [@gore85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11561569/gore85) mentioned, this might be an issue with Windows 10 version 1903. I was on 1903 insider preview builds when I posted this question (it's out now) and he's seeing the same thing after updating to 1903.

Comment: I am guessing that you are getting close votes in the 'off-topic' category because you have not included enough information to duplicate this problem.

Comment: @Stewbob I've updated the question to clarify this. This is the behavior I'm seeing on a blank WPF project, with no code changes at all. If nobody else can reproducte the issue, then the answer might lie in an issue with my system, not the framework. But I don't know yet if that's happening for anyone else or not.

Comment: if it's on a blank WPF project, your guess about it being hardware related is probably a good guess.  Your question will probably still attract close votes in that case, since hardware-related issues often get closed as 'off-topic' as well.

Comment: This almost feels like a video driver issue.  There's even options in the Control Panel under System Properties' Performance section that could wholly enable/disable this sort of 'visibility' of the window upon size change requests.  **That said,** I'm unable to reproduce in a brand new WPF application on my side, also in several .net iterations.

Comment: @gravitymixes It's unlikely to be a video driver issue, as it's happening when running on my Intel or my Nvidia GPU. And it can't be the setting as it does not have a consistent behavior. Thanks for the test, by the way. Good to know that it's isolated to my machine, and users won't see such behavior.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi - does this happen running through VS or as stand alone?

Comment: @Kixoka Both. I also tried Debug/Release configs, but that does not make a difference either.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I upgraded my Windows from 1809 to 1903 and I think its related to that. Before my wpf projects resized perfectly, but now its the same as shown in your video.

Comment: @gore85 Huh, that might make sense. I was on 1903 (insider preview back then) on my PC, and I was not able to replicate this issue myself on a PC running 1809.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this issue now.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517211/windows-10-update-kb4517211

> Addresses an issue with resizing Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   applications; they may not respond to being resized using the mouse
>   until you release the mouse button.

It seems to stem from a faulty tablet input support. Someone devised [a workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/573655/wpf-mouse-capture-issue-windows-10-1903.html) (without using the update):

```
public static void DisableWPFTabletSupport()
        {
            // Get a collection of the tablet devices for this window.    
            TabletDeviceCollection devices = System.Windows.Input.Tablet.TabletDevices;


            if (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                // Get the Type of InputManager.  
                Type inputManagerType = typeof(System.Windows.Input.InputManager);


                // Call the StylusLogic method on the InputManager.Current instance.  
                object stylusLogic = inputManagerType.InvokeMember("StylusLogic",
                            BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                            null, InputManager.Current, null);


                if (stylusLogic != null)
                {
                    // Get the type of the stylusLogic returned 
                    // from the call to StylusLogic.  
                    Type stylusLogicType = stylusLogic.GetType();


                    // Loop until there are no more devices to remove.  
                    while (devices.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Remove the first tablet device in the devices collection.  
                        stylusLogicType.InvokeMember("OnTabletRemoved",
                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                null, stylusLogic, new object[] { (uint)0 });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the sort of "fix" that will create problem in years to come when other changes are made to windows.    Hence at a minimum make it conditional on the version of Windows.  However I rather make the app show a clear message box saying wndowa needs updating and explaining way.